# The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context in Razor

Tags: .net, io, asp.net-core-mvc, httpcontext

I feel a little stupid here, because I have been working on this for some hours now.

I got a simple Razor-page where I want to check if a file exists. When I use "HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath" and I run the page, I get the "HttpContext does not exist"-error.

I also tried  HostingEnvironment.MapPath (as is visible in the commented line, Using System.Web.Hosting), but that didn't work either. This is all quite new to me, so it could be I'm missing something. As far as I know, referenced the correct libraries.

```
    @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IViewLocalizer Localizer
    @model IEnumerable<SensorView>
    @using System.IO;
    @using System.Web;

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            @{
                if (Model != null)
                {
                    foreach (SensorView sensor in Model)
                    {
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                @{
                                    @*<img src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~{0}.jpg", sensor.Image))" alt="@sensor.Image" class="sensor-image" />*@

                                var absolutePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~{0}.jpg", sensor.Image));
                                //var absolutePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(string.Format("~{0}.jpg", sensor.Image));
                                if (File.Exists(absolutePath))
                                {
                                        <img src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~{0}.jpg", sensor.Image))" alt="@sensor.Image" class="sensor-image" />
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <img src="@Url.Content(@"images/sensoren/320x150.png")" alt="@sensor.Image" class="sensor-image" />
                                    }
                                }
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>
                                        <a asp-action="Detail" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-SensorId="@sensor.ID" role="link">@sensor.Title</a>
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                        @sensor.DescriptionShort
                                    </p>
                                    <a asp-action="Detail" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-SensorId="@sensor.ID" class="btn btn-info _trMoreInformation" role="button">@Localizer["MoreInformation"]</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

I thought it would be straightforward but as said, I have been working on this for a few hours now without any progress.

It could be the hot weather ;-)

Anyway, what I try to accomplice is check if a file exists, if not show a default image.

Any help is appreciated.

[Update]

The project structure is visible in the picture below.[image]

I ended up with the following code. This works for me.

```
    @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IViewLocalizer Localizer
@model IEnumerable<SensorView>
@using System.IO;
@using System.Web;


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        @{
            if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (SensorView sensor in Model)
                {
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            @{
                                @*<img src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~{0}.jpg", sensor.Image))" alt="@sensor.Image" class="sensor-image" />*@


                                if (HostingEnvironment.ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo(string.Format("wwwroot{0}.jpg", sensor.Image)).Exists)
                                {
                                    <img src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~{0}.jpg", sensor.Image))" alt="@sensor.Image" class="sensor-image" />
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <img src="@Url.Content(@"/images/sensoren/320x150.png")" alt="@sensor.Image" class="sensor-image" />
                                }
                            }
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 style="min-height:40px;">
                                    <a asp-action="Detail" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-SensorId="@sensor.ID" role="link">@sensor.Title</a>
                                </h4>
                                <div style="min-height:80px;">
                                    <p>
                                        @sensor.DescriptionShort
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <a asp-action="Detail" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-SensorId="@sensor.ID" class="btn btn-info _trMoreInformation" role="button">@Localizer["MoreInformation"]</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using with
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Comment: Yes, tried both (see the commented part in the code)

Comment: Where did you store image and what is the value for `sensor.Image`? Share us your project structure. Do you deveop with `MVC Razor View` or `Razor Page(PageModel)`?

Comment: @Edward, Image is just a property of the SensorModel holding the name of the image. I need the name to show the image like <img src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~{0}.jpg", sensor.Image))". This works fine, but prior I would like to check if the file exists. I cannot get that to work.

Comment: @Edward3, thx for all the support. I will add an image of the project structure. I use the MVC Razor Views (with shared partial views).

Comment: Share us the generated image url and where image is in the server project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are using a Razor Pages Web App, you missed `@page` and need add `@page`  directive on the top of the cshtml file to make it compiled as a class inherits indirectly from IRazorPage . As a result ,you will have a HttpContext Property .
2. To get a `HostingEnvironment`, you can inject it by  `@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment`, thus you can check whether the file exist via `ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo(subfilepath).Exists` .
3. Just as a reminder , if you want to serve static files under the root path of project , don’t forget to `UseStaticFiles(staticFileOpts)`  .

Comment: I was able to solve the issue using your suggestions in the second option. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct syntax is:

```
var absolutePath = Context.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~{0}.jpg", sensor.Image));
```

Maybe [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.1) will help you find the most fit approach.